# Services_Twitter Pear PHP code - OAuth direct messages suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have the following PHP code, which up to a week or so ago was working to send Twitter direct messages to a particular user. I now get "**HTTP_OAuth_Exception: Unable to connect to tcp://api.twitter.com:80. Error #0: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name of service not known in /usr/share/pear/HTTP/OAuth/Consumer.php on line 257**"

I've searched around and can't find that anything has changed with Twitter since it was working and the server configuration also hasn't changed. I tried using SSL in case Twitter suddenly required connection via SSL, but that gave basically the same error (except it said ssl and port 443).

I'm at a loss to see what's wrong and don't believe anything changed on my side.  My code is based on the example in the Services_Twitter documentation (http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Twitter/docs/latest/Services_Twitter/Services_Twitter.html#var$oauth)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   require_once 'Services/Twitter.php';
   require_once 'HTTP/OAuth/Consumer.php';

   $twitterto = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
   $message='This is a test message';

   $cons_key='xxxxxxxxxxxx';
   $cons_sec='xxxxxxxxxxxx';
   $auth_tok='xxxxxxxxxxxx';
   $tok_sec='xxxxxxxxxxxx';

try {
   $twitter = new Services_Twitter();
   $oauth = new HTTP_OAuth_Consumer($cons_key,
                                    $cons_sec,
                                    $auth_tok,
                                    $tok_sec);

   $twitter->setOAuth($oauth);

   // The error is raised on the following line.
   $twitter->direct_messages->new($twitterto, $message);

   $twitter->account->end_session();
} catch (Services_Twitter_Exception $e) {

     echo $e->getMessage();

}
```